# Multicore Forth, is there one?

Tags: multicore, forth

Does such a implementation of Forth exists that allows you to take full advantage of multicore processors?

Answer (score 6):

I recently became aware of [colorForth](http://www.colorforth.com/) which is the latest invention from Mr Moore (not ANS compliant) and is used on his new multicore [chips](http://www.greenarraychips.com).

It features 144 small forth computers on a single chip (and no clock!) for high efficiency.

EDIT:
Actually, colorForth is the IDE used for the chips. The flavor of (color)Forth running on the chip is called arrayForth.

Comment: Now [Green Arrays](http://www.greenarraychips.com/) have opened up [arrayForth Institue](http://school.arrayforth.com/). So far, there's only one introductory course to attend; but more is under development.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently.  I don't know much about it, see *[Multicore processors, FORTH programming, and the relationship between software and silicon](http://drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/210603608)*  (published 2008-09-24).

You want to take "full advantage" of multicore processors.  The excuse for multicore programming is that you need performance (you can do multithreaded with just one CPU).

In that case, I don't think I'd use Forth, as it is fundamentally an interpreter (yes, a fairly fast one).
Worse, for modern processors, each Forth word-dispatch being an indirect call is likely a pipeline break, which really slams processor performance, and Forth word-execution operates on stack elements instead of registers.  So by using Forth, you are giving up computational advantage compared to C or C++ or even Fortran.  What this means is that you are almost gauranteed to have to use more than one CPU with Forth to match the performance of a more traditionally coded and compiled language.  Why start with a disadvantage?

The guys that want to do MP with Python puzzle me for the same reason.

Comment: Would you really classify Forth as an interpreter? Surely it is up to you what is compiled and what is interpreted?

Comment: @sheepez: Yes It doesn't generate machine instructions, so you can't call it a native code compiler. In fact, what it does generate isn't very complicated: for each Forth word, store a pointer corresponding to that Fort word. AFAIK, it will compile any sequence of Forth word; semantic checks are left entirely to runtime. That matches what interpreters typically do.

Comment: There actually are implementations that compile words into sequences of native CALL instructions. Some will even inline specific words.

Comment: I really ought to treat you to a -1 for this answer, but I'm being nice today.  You are confusing the language FORTH with the usual implementation of FORTH as an indirect-threaded code interpreter.  This is a very common error.  There is no reason whatsoever why FORTH could not be implemented with a traditional compiler, doing traditional optimizations, caching the first few stack locations in dedicated registers.  (And note that the register-starved x86 architecture, including multicore parts, ALREADY spends a lot of its time bouncing stack elements around, even on C/C++ or even FORTRAN.)

Comment: @John: OP asked if there was an implementation that would let him go parallel effectively.   My response: likely not, since most implementations are traditional, and those are disasterous for parallel programming.  If you know of a single implementation that has the nice properties you describe, and could be used effectively by OP, you are welcome to post it as a direct answer to OP's question.  If you do not know of one, then I think my answer is reasonable.  Successful parallel programs aren't about what might be theoretically possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are Forth implementations that run on the bare-metal that DO compile machine code, and if you do a bit of research before you start typing you will see that in-fact:

1. Forth was the personal system in use by Chuck Moore since 1958
2. Forth is a language, a compiler, and operating system, an interactive debugger (where you get this idea of it being "interpreted") a bare-metal-as-Chuck-intended Forth system gets even better when you consider that this entire WORLD needs only 2 registers, and ALU, and a Program Counter to run. Programming in Forth is completely different than the stuff your operating system is likely made out of and so I think one should really look at "bare-metal" or even native (yes there are native stack machine processors) Forths before judging what is what.
3. it was exactly these "bare-metal" Forth implementations what were used for decades and are still highly used today in embedded devices where your desktop OS should probably never go.

Comment: oops sorry i should have merely added a comment above... didnt mean to put an answer. im not actually an answer kind of guy.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question?

Answer (score 2):

Multicore Forth programming is possible with iForth. There are 32/64 bit implementations that work on Win7, Linux, and OS X. iForth generates native code: http://home.iae.nl/users/mhx/i4faq.html

Answer (score 0):

In general each language that have a full interface to an underling operating system, tend to be able to use all facilities, including the possibility to fork and run parts of this in parallel. Under linux that means you need a general facility for system calls, under MS-Windows DLL-calls. In the free ciforth family of Forth's this is called XOS in linux : *par1 par2 par3 N_### XOS*. In MS-Windows *CALL[ ... ]CALL.*
Based on this system call you can have pre-emptive parallel processing libraries, not much different from what is possible in C. Under MS-Windows you have DLL-calls, that provide the same facilities, but they tend to hard on Forth because they are documented for the c-perspective.
Ciforth has a library definitions, using CREATE DOES>
Create a thread with dictionary SPACE. Execute XT in thread:

```
 1024 THREAD-PET parallel 
: hello "Hello world!" CR ;
'hello parallel
 Hello world! OK
```

As the word *hello* doesn't contain an infinite loop, it automatically terminates.

Most commercial programs have similar facilities, but it is not standardised, if that is what you're after.